# Attempting to remove sql db in azure gives error "No default subscription has been designated"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am currently trying to write a powershell script which logs into azure and then deletes an SQL database.
When it gets to the database deletion it gives an error:

```
Remove-AzureSqlDatabase : No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default <subscriptionName> to set the default 
subscription.
```

When i try to add a default subscription with `Select-AzureSubscription -Default -SubscriptionName Pay-As-You-Go` i get an error aswell:

```
Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription name Pay-As-You-Go doesn't exist.
```

I'm confused as to what the problem is and have tried connecting to the account via `connect-AzAccount` aswell.

The full script is:

```
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString password -AsPlainText -Force
$pscredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('accountname', $passwd)
Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $pscredential -Tenant "tenant string" 
# Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "subscription id"
Select-AzureSubscription -Default -SubscriptionName Pay-As-You-Go
# Get-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName “Pay-As-You-Go” | Select-AzureSubscription -Default

Remove-AzureSqlDatabase -ServerName migrate -DatabaseName "AWS-Copy"
```

Comment: Have you tried placing the name in quotes? Or tried via `-SubscriptionId` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not mix the three powershell module `Azure`, `Az`, `AzureRm` together, and if you have installed the [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-1.8.0) module, I recommend you to uninstall the `AzureRm` module, it was deprecated and will never be updated.

To remove sql db with `Az` module, your script should be like below. Make sure your account has an RBAC role(e.g. `Owner`, `Contributor`) of your subscription/SQL Server.

```
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString password -AsPlainText -Force
$pscredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('accountname', $passwd)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $pscredential -Tenant "<tenant-id>" 
Set-AzContext -Subscription "<subscription-id>"
Remove-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -ServerName "<ServerName>" -DatabaseName "<DatabaseName>"
```